# "Wir nachverfolgen unseren Müll nicht" Jargon oder Grammatikfehler?

Tags: grammar

In einer Fernsehdiskussion zur Mülltrennung der Bundeswehr im Auslandeinsatz (*"Hart aber fair"* vom 25.6.2012) bin ich auf folgendes Zitat gestoßen:

> *"Wir nachverfolgen unseren Müll nicht"*<sup>[Hart aber fair](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TytbfJ9zDhU)</sup>

Handelt es sich hier um eine grammatikalische Besonderheit im Bundeswehrjargon? Gibt es dafür Regeln oder Gründe?

Comment: Sieht aus wie Telegrammstil ("ankomme morgen früh").

Comment: @musiKk: ja, ziemlich ähnlich, aber nicht ganz. Es wäre eher wie *"Ich ankomme morgen früh"*.

Comment: @userunknown: nicht unbedingt: "nach­ver­fol­gen - Wortart: schwaches Verb - den Ablauf von etwas verfolgen (3) oder nachträglich ausfindig machen" [http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nachverfolgen] :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Das ist ein Grammatikfehler. Es sollte heißen:

> *Wir verfolgen unseren Müll nicht nach.*

obwohl ich das immer noch als Stilblüte betrachten würde. Am besten fände ich:

> *Wir verfolgen den (Entsorgungs-)Weg unseres Mülls nicht nach.* [je nach Kontext]

Allgemein könnte man fragen: Wenn man ein Verb hat, das sich aus [Präposition](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4position) + Verb zusammensetzt, wann darf man diese beiden Bestandteile trennen, so dass es immer noch einen korrekten Satz gibt?

Eine allgemeine Regel, wann man Präposition + Verb trennt, gibt es allerdings nicht, das hängt immer von der Bedeutung des Worts ab.

Beispiel: *vorausgehen* und *übergehen*. Ersteres kann man trennen, Letzteres nicht.

Genauso: *Wegtragen* und *(sich) vertragen*.

Comment: Im Kontext würde ich übrigens sagen, dass das hier ein Beispiel ist, wenn man einen englischen Satz übersetzt und den Satzbau nicht 100% anpasst. Führungssoldaten im Auslandseinsatz sprechen ja nur Englisch mit Soldaten anderer Armeen und dieser hat das anscheinend so internalisiert, so dass er einfach deutschen und englischen Satzbau vermischt.

Comment: Geht doch wohl! "Wir gehen langsam über die Brücke" ;)

Comment: Die Regel ist ganz einfach: Wenn der erste Wortteil betont ist, wird getrennt. Wenn der zweite Wortteil betont ist, wird nicht getrennt. In "vorausgehen" liegt die Betonung auf "voraus", also wird getrennt ("ich gehe voraus"). In "übergehen" liegt die Betonung auf "gehen", also wird nicht getrennt ("ich übergehe"). Bei manchen Wörtern gibt es beides: "umstellen" im Sinne von "sich um ein Objekt herum postieren" hat die Betonung auf "stellen", daher "die Polizei umstellt das Haus", aber bei "umstellen" als "etwas anders hinstellen" ist "um" betont, also getrennt: "Ich stelle die Möbel um."

Comment: BTW, "übergehen" gibt es auch trennbar: "Ihm geht das Herz über."

Comment: @celtschk Die Definition mit der Betonung scheint mir allerdings umgedreht oder zirkulär - woher weiß ich als nicht-Muttersprachler, wie ich welches Wort zu betonen habe? Man könnte die Definition genausogut umkehren - Wenn ich die Präposition vom Verb trennen kann, dann betone ich es so, ansonsten anders.

Comment: "Wir übergehen Frank bei der Wahl zum Klassensprecher" aber "Wir überqueren die Brücke" - nicht **übergehen**. "Wir verfolgen unseren Müll nicht.". Für ein "nach" ist da gar kein Anlass.

Comment: @userunknown Krieg ich jetzt eine downvote weil dein Sprachempfinden nicht mit dem des Zitierten übereinstimmt? "Nachverfolgen" ist ein ganz normales Wort mit einer Bedeutung, die nicht identisch ist mit "verfolgen"; selbst wenn es identisch wäre, wäre das immer noch kein Grund. Bewerte meine Antwort, nicht den Satz, nach dem gefragt wird.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatikfehler durch unnötige Verdoppelung.
Der Satz könnte genauso gut

> *Wir verfolgen unseren Müll nicht.*

heißen, und nichts wäre verloren.

"Nach" fügt der Aussage nichts hinzu, weil eine Verfolgung dem verfolgten Objekt stets nach-*folgt*.

Comment: Dem stimme ich nicht ganz zu. Die Bedeutung "Die Entwicklung/Der Ablauf eines Prozesses beobachten" kann sowohl mit "verfolgen" als auch "nachverfolgen" wiedergegeben werden. Verwendet man jedoch "nachverfolgen", so kann auch gemeint sein, dass man "nicht versucht, im Nachhinein den Prozess zu rekonstruieren". Ich denke, dass im Kontext der reine "Beobachtungsprozess" gemeint ist, daher ist es - der Einfachheit zu liebe - tatsächlich am sinnvollsten auf das *nach* zu verzichten.

Comment: Ich glaube, wir verwenden für eine Aussage wie in Deinem Beispiel zwar häufig "nachverfolgen", aber meinen tatsächlich "nachvollziehen".
"Einen Prozess nachverfolgen" klingt nach eine neuere Bildung aus der Geschäftssprache - steckt dahinter vielleicht ein Fremdsprachenimport?

Comment: "Einen Prozess nachverfolgen" klingt wirklich schäbig, dennoch nicht falsch. Besser klingt es schon, wenn man Ablauf, Verlauf oder Vorgang nimmt. Aber auch dann noch bescheiden. Aber "nachvollziehen" ist nicht gemeint, zumindest nicht in den Kontexten, die ich so im Hinterkopf habe. Z.B. eine Transaktion nachverfolgen, ein Päckchen nachverfolgen; oder im Bereich Computer den Weg von Daten nachverfolgen. Entscheidend ist eben, dass der Verlauf, Prozess, Ablauf oder Vorgang bereits abgeschlossen ist und man im Nachhinein nun versucht herauszufinden, welchen Weg das gesuchte Medium genommen hat.

Comment: Da die einzige Aussage der Antwort darin besteht, dass nachverfolgen und verfolgen das gleiche ist, -1. Die Aussage ist nicht wahr denn ersten: kann nachverfolgen nicht immer für verfolgen eingesetzt werden und zweitens ist nachverfolgen ein Wort im Duden. Die Überschneidung mag groß sein, doch einen Prozess verfolgen kann man nur "life" während nachverfolgen auch später noch geht.

Comment: @UrsReupke: Im einen Fall beschreibt das Verb das verstohlene Hinterhergehen, wobei das Objekt auf der Flucht ist; im anderen Fall beschreibt es das aufmerksame Überwachen eines Vorgangs, wobei nicht mal eine tatsächliche Bewegung stattfinden muss. Im ersteren Fall ist "nachverfolgen" tatsächlich nicht sinnvoll - aber in der vorliegenden Diskussion ging es ja eben gerade um die Prozessverfolgung, nicht um Beuteverfolgung :)

Comment: Kommentare bereinigt. Die ganze Diskussion geht am Thema komplett vorbei. Ob die beiden Verben dasselbe bedeuten oder nicht, ist vollkommen irrelevant. Denn selbst wenn sie es tun, ist die Antwort trotzdem falsch. "Unnötige Verdoppelung" ist kein Grammatikfehler. "Weißer Schimmel" ist grammatikalisch einwandfrei. So einfach ist das, daher -1. Alle Parteien werden erinnert, daß längere Diskussionen in den Chat gehören.