# »Er anerkennt die Grenzen« – korrektes Deutsch?

Tags: grammaticality, separable-verb

Neulich gelesen, und anscheinend auch nicht so ungewöhnlich:

> Er anerkennt die Grenzen.

([Google results](https://www.google.no/search?q=%22er%20anerkennt%20die%20grenzen%22); hat es sogar in die FAZ geschafft)

Ich erkenne nur

> Er erkennt die Grenzen an

als richtiges Deutsch an. Oder habe ich etwas verpasst?

Comment: Ich hätte das zunächst mit [Schweizerhochdeutsch](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schweizer_Hochdeutsch#Beispiele) in Verbindung gebracht.

Comment: Da sich Schreibende ihren Text gern vorlesen und "er er..." ein Zungenbrecher ist und auch so klingt, entscheiden sich dann wohl manche für das geschmeidigere "er an...". Bei "sie er..." und "sie an..." ist der Unterschied nicht so groß.

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4844/wir-nachverfolgen-unseren-m%c3%bcll-nicht-jargon-oder-grammatikfehler

Answer (score 4):

Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anerkennen) ist beides richtig, aber "erkennt an" gebräuchlicher.

Answer (score 3):

Laut Duden – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* wird bei *anerkennen* in den finiten Formen des Verberst- und Verbzweitsatzes der Verbzusatz *an-* im Allgemeinen vom Verb getrennt und nachgestellt. (Beim Infinitiv, den Partizipien und im Nebensatz mit Einleitewort [Verbletztsatz] geht allerdings der Verbzusatz *an-* dem Rest der Verbform voraus und wird mit diesem zusammengeschrieben.)

> Er erkennt einige ihrer Forderungen uneingeschränkt an.

Vor allem in juristischen und theologischen Texten besteht jedoch die Neigung, *an-* als Präfix anzusehen und nicht zu trennen. Die ungetrennten Formen findet man auch im schweizerischen und österreichischen Sprachgebrauch.

> sie anerkennt